# css бегущая строка: одинаковая скорость прокрутки для разных по ширине блоков

Tags: css, jquery, transition

Прошу помощи: пишу простенький скрипт бегущей строки. Хочу сделать чтобы блоки с разной длиной контента, и как следствие с разной шириной, имели одинаковую скорость прокрутки, но очевидно, что общее время, к примеру 2s, заставляет прокручиваться блоки с разной шириной с разной скоростью. Просьба подсказать: как рассчитать это время *s, исходя из разной ширины прокручиваемого блока, чтобы скорость движения была блока была одинакова вне зависимости от его ширины.

```js
function run()
{
let position = parseInt($('a').width()) - parseInt($(".marquee").width())
$('a').css("left", "-"  + position + "px").css("transition", "left 2s linear")
}
```

```css
.marquee
{
display: block;
height: 50px;
width: 500px;
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

a
{
display: block;
position: absolute; 
top: 0;
left: 100%;
white-space: nowrap; 
background: #f2beec;
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">
<a href="">Еще текст какой то, но он будет очень длинным, чтобы он гарантированно не уместился в поле и ему нужно было бы бежать справа налево Еще текст какой то, но он будет очень длинным, чтобы он гарантированно не уместился в поле и ему нужно было бы бежать справа налево</a>
</div>
<button onclick="run(); return false">Поехали!</button>
```

Comment: Попробуйте не привязываться к длине строки, а просто задать скорость прокрутки, например, в пикселях в секунду. При этом блоки будут прокручиваться с одинаковой скоростью независимо от их длины.  Ну и надо будет отслеживать наступление концов блоков, чтобы начинать прокрутку заново.